# Stream filter using Predicate to fetch latest record

Tags: java, lambda, java-stream, predicate

I have a method of type boolean which returns stream of data of Predicate type Incident, I want to filter out the latest incident only.

Comment: Do you mean you need to find that last element of your `Stream` that passes that filter? Is `forloebs` a `List`?

Comment: Why was the code removed?

Comment: as it was not a sample code

Answer (score 3):

You have to check all elements in stream. You can collect all filtered elements to `LinkedList` and get the last one.

```java
forloebs.stream()
.filter(predicate)
.collect(Collectors.toCollection(LinkedList::new)).peekLast();
```

[peekLast](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html#peekLast()) will return `null` if this list is empty.

Comment: `null` can be handled with `Optional` in this case

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `max` function to get latest incident that matches your `completeincident` condition.

```
Optional<Incident> latestIncident = forloebs.stream()
 .filter(completeincident)
 .max(Comparator.comparing(x -> x.getDateIncident()));
```

The comparator will keep the latest element based on `getDateIncident`.

It will return `Optional.Empty` if none of them matches filter criteria.